Is a non-repayable foreign business incentives policy feasible?
Assume a nation state creates a fund that any of its citizens can use to start a business in a developing country, proportional to the percentage of population immigrating from that country into theirs. The amount disbursed by the state for such businesses also doesn't need to be repaid.
In practice it seems to me this already happens all the time in the private sector, just only big corporations or nation states-backed companies have the capital to do it with reduced risk.
What are the possible drawbacks of such a policy, which the strength points? How it could be implemented in practice? Is it feasible at all?

Why would any state want to do such a program? What would be the intended goals? And why would it be "proportional to the percentage of population immigrating from that country"?

"The amount disbursed by the state for such businesses also doesn't need to be repaid." Unless I am misunderstanding something, this is begging to be abused.

"What are the possible drawbacks of such a policy, which the strength points?" This is not clear to me. Drawbacks or strengths certainly depend on what you want to achieve. What do you want to achieve with this idea? "Is it feasible at all?" Again not clear. Do you mean that it can be formalized or that people will like it or something else?

I imagine this talks about a tax for using immigrant labor, which is then used to create jobs in immigration supplying countries to reduce further immigrant labor offering.

Percentage of what? Percentage of the source country population, percentage as the destination population, percentage of the emmigrants in that year, or what?

@Philipp Why would any state want to do such a program? My best guess is that this is being considered as a potential policy to reduce immigration using "capitalistic" ideas.

Any sane program like that would come with bureaucratic oversight to check that the business proposal was viable, and that the money was used accordingly. This precludes most individuals and very small startups because they cannot handle the forms.
The remaining question would be if a program like that should be for any business idea, or for specific fields of policy which the sponsor wants to push, and if it should select recipient countries based on the number of immigrants a country gets.

Consider how many people are coming to Europe from Syria or Afghanistan, because those countries are bad places to live. Should the program promote investment in those countries?
On the other hand, many countries receive immigrants from countries which are not in serious need of subsidized investment, e.g. Polish immigrants in the UK or Italians in Germany.
Given limited public funds (they all come from taxes, ultimately, and nobody likes taxes ...) it makes sense to target subsidies where private industry does not invest on their own.


A direct grant, from country X, for someone to fund a business in country Y to provide jobs for the citizens of country Y, keeping them in country Y rather than immigrating to country X?
A total waste of money.  Think about it.  A company employing a 1000 people durably will take a lot of money to set up.  Assume it operates at the same general failure rate of other businesses in country Y, you may have to set up several before one sticks.
In the meantime, you've done what?  Kept 1000 worker in Y?  Many of whom probably would not have immigrated to X in the first place. * Not 1000 per year foregone and avoided immigrants either, 1000 total, until the company stops.
You'd have to bleed money for years before this kind of direct cash injection showed up on your immigration stats, which, in order for this policy to be considered would have to be seeing orders of magnitude more immigrants from Y than 1000/year.
And that's before scams and the cost of the required oversight by country X bureaucrats (who would have to travel to Y frequently).
Not to say encouraging economic development in Y, by X isn't a good idea.  It is.  But it shouldn't be done, in the proposed fashion, on the backs of X's taxpayers.  There are other, less costly and less risky, mechanisms (which may still have to get funded by X's taxpayers).

happens all the time in the private sector, just only big corporations

That's not a bug, that's a feature.  You want the private sector in X to be funding it and taking the risks.  Plus, presumably (hah!), the people doing it know whatever business domain they are targeting.  Which wouldn't be the case with X bureaucrats.
Country X assisting country Y to boost its education?  Sure.  Facilities for Y expats to reverse immigrate back to Y with repayable loans to start up businesses in Y?  Mmmh, maybe.  Plenty of things to look at.  Multilateral organizations like the IMF, World Bank or UN.
But not this question's proposal of outright grants.
* This is for example a frequent criticism of carbon offset schemes:  sure, you've "saved" a forest.  But it is quite possible you just paid for something that would have happened anyway.  And, if the forest is cut down 30 years later, you haven't gotten all that much for your $.
p.s. Dependents do have a multiplicative effect in Y, but they are hard to account for as illegal immigration wouldn't necessarily result in them showing up in X along with the now stabilized worker of this hypothesis.
p.p.s.  Other types of programs.  Like EU grants for Turkey to keep (non-Turkish) refugees from right-next door EU?  Or stuff to keep boats from launching in Tunisia?  Those are different programs and need to be weighed on their merits.

Nonetheless, it's more or less what the EU does with Turkey to keep the Syrians there. Except it's not even called/pretending to be an investment.

The difference is that you know what you are getting.  Pay X get Y less immigrants.  You also know that the immigrants are already there in Turkey to get to the next door EU (see my forest example above).  Not the same thing.

"Not to say encouraging economic development in Y, by X isn't a good idea. It is. But it shouldn't be done on the backs of X's taxpayers." The World Bank etc. are all pretty much in the business of doing that. As are some more obscure EU programs conditioned on stymieing migrants through Africa. The latter same clear[er] targets, but nowhere near as clear as that deal with Turkey. https://www.lemonde.fr/en/le-monde-africa/article/2024/05/21/how-eu-funds-enable-north-african-countries-to-push-back-europe-bound-migrants-into-the-desert_6672115_124.html

I suppose some higher-ups in the EU know what they're really buying with that with more figures, but most of those don't make it to the press.
